# Is there a way to load the `<router-outlet>` in another `<router-outlet>`?

Tags: angular

I want to open the `<router-outlet>` in the other `<router-outlet>`

I used the

```
  { outlet:"admin",path: 'AdminDashboard/Users', component: AdminUsersComponent},
```

and

```
      <router-outlet name="admin"></router-outlet>
```

But when I click on the link the page doesn't load

Is there a way to load the `<router-outlet>` in another `<router-outlet>`?

---

yes ,sure

my app-routing.module.ts :

```
const routes: Routes = [
          {  path: '', redirectTo: '/index', pathMatch: 'full' },
          {  path: 'index', component: SiteMainPageComponent },
          { path: 'AdminDashboard', component: AdminMainPageComponent },
           { outlet:"admin",path: 'AdminDashboard/Users', component: AdminUsersComponent},

        ];
    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Follow this link: https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-router-multiple-outlets/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you do nested router-outlets is that you set the children of a route and put the nested router-outlet in that route (MyNestedRouteComponent in this case).

```
const routes: Routes = [
      {  path: '', redirectTo: '/index', pathMatch: 'full' },
      {  path: 'nested-router', component: MyNestedRouteComponent, children: [{
         // nested routes here
      }] },
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

what you have is correct, so, the problem should be another way, could you incldue the full router file?

Answer (score 0):

What does your template look like?  Here's the syntax:

```
Syntax: <a [routerLink]="[{outlets: { <outlet name> : [<path>]}}>Text</a>
```

Try this:

```
<a [routerLink]="[{outlets: { admin: ['AdminDashboard/Users']} }]">Users</a>
```

Comment: Not sure if that's what you're looking for.  Good luck.